# controller not a function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a problem. my routes do not find my controllers except /vehicules
**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.grid']);
 angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
     // route for the home page
         .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
         controller: ''
     })


     .when('/vehicules', {
         templateUrl: 'views/vehicules.html',
         controller: 'VehiculeCtrl'
     })


     .when('/vehicule/:id', {
         templateUrl: 'views/vehicule.html',
         controller: 'VoirVehiculeCtrl'
     })


     .when('/agents', {
         templateUrl: 'views/agents.html',
         controller: 'AgentsCtrl'
     })


     .when('/agences', {
         templateUrl: 'views/agences.html',
         controller: 'AgencesCtrl'
     })


     .when('/status', {
         templateUrl: 'views/status.html',
         controller: 'StatusCtrl'
     })

     .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
     });
});
```

**VoirVehiculeCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('VoirVehiculeCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

my tree:

- Javascript

  - controllers

    - VehiculeCtrl.js
    - VoirVehiculeCtrl.js
  - App.js
- Views

please help me !! and sorry for my english xD

Comment: are you sure you included all the files?

Comment: you probably have missed adding script in html

Comment: Yes you are right guys !!! i'm sorry ^^